# How can I use the LIKE operator to make this match in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to match a price string, like $25.00, to find the corresponding currency symbol.  For example, $25.00 should match USD.  This much is working; however when I pass in 25.00 (no currency symbol), then I have an unwanted match on CUP.

I have the following table set up in SQL Server 2012:

```
CurrencyId  varchar(3)
Symbol      nvarchar
```

Here is some of the data:

```
Currency Symbol
ANG      ƒ
CUP      ₱
EUR      €
USD      $
```

The query is:

```
SELECT [t0].[CurrencyId], [t0].[Symbol]
FROM [dbo].[EWN_Currency] AS [t0]
WHERE '25.00' LIKE '%'+[t0].[Symbol]+'%'
```

If I skip the string concatenation for testing, then it at least doesn't return the bad match, such as:

```
SELECT [t0].[CurrencyId], [t0].[Symbol]
FROM [dbo].[EWN_Currency] AS [t0]
WHERE '25.00' LIKE '%₱%'
```

It seems the string concatenation isn't setup correctly with LIKE '%'+[t0].[Symbol]+'%'.  I've played with converting everything to nvarchar without luck.  How would I make this work?  Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like an issue concatenating with that character. Can it be made to work using the `CHARINDEX` function instead (which could be done without concatenating)?

Comment: Your query works fine for me.  What version of SQL Server?

Comment: I'm using the 2012 version.  Also, testing with WHERE '25.00' LIKE N'%₱%' returns the whole table.

Comment: I think it is a unicode versus non-unicode match issue. Try `N'₱25.00' Like N'%₱%'`. Both sides of the operator need to be the same datatype or an implicit conversion will occur and potentially screw up the results.

Answer (score 2):

How about using `LEFT`?

```
SELECT *
FROM   TableName
WHERE  LEFT('$25.00',1) = Symbol
```

- [SQLFIddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/26293/1)

Comment: WHERE  LEFT('₱25.00',1) = Symbol returns no rows, expected one row

Comment: WHERE  LEFT('$25.00',1) = Symbol returns one row for USD as expected.  WHERE  LEFT('25.00',1) = Symbol returns no row as expected.  Still there is this odd bevahior with the ₱ character.   Thanks JW.

Comment: here's for `₱`, http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/26293/2 it seems that there is a problem with the charcater collation.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
with cte as
(select [Symbol], [CurrencyId] from [dbo].[EWN_Currency] where [Symbol] = '₱')
SELECT coalesce([t0].[CurrencyId], cte.[CurrencyId]) [CurrencyId],
       coalesce([t0].[Symbol], cte.[Symbol]) [Symbol]
FROM cte
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[EWN_Currency] AS [t0]
       ON '25.00' LIKE '%'+[t0].[Symbol]+'%'
```

Note: If you intend to use this with a table of currency-formatted data rather than a single string then I suggest cross joining from the cte to your data table, then left joining from the data table to the currency table.

(SQLFiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1a175/1))