# SQL : Select text containing cyrillic character

Tags: sql

I want to select in my table the text containing ₽

I tried this :

```
SELECT raw_text
    FROM table
    WHERE raw_text LIKE N'%₽%'

SELECT raw_text
    FROM table
    WHERE raw_text LIKE '%₽%'
```

But my output rows does not contained ₽ : how should I pass this character in my query ?

Comment: what RDBMS do you use?

Comment: [Works for me](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=5ebc41184626600db712f80ddb6a2813)

Comment: @Sergey I use SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

```
     create table the_table (raw_text nvarchar(10));
     insert into the_table values (N'₽');
     go

     SELECT raw_text
     FROM the_table
     WHERE raw_text LIKE N'%₽%'

     drop table the_table;
```

Tested on MS SQL Server 2017

Comment: My issue it that with this N'%₽%' I have a lot of string that does not have ₽ in the output. Can you test to insert some row without ₽ ?

Comment: Please take a look on the following topic exactly about rubels https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47676627/inserting-special-character-in-sql-server

Comment: create table the_table (raw_text nvarchar(10)COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS);
insert into the_table values (NCHAR(8381)),(N'UAH'),(N'GBP');
go
SELECT raw_text
FROM the_table
WHERE raw_text COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS LIKE NCHAR(8381)collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

drop table the_table;

Comment: Thanks, I already saw this topic but I don't see how I can integrate NCHAR(8381) into my LIKE condition with the wildcard

Comment: I tried to declare like this "DECLARE @rubels NCHAR(8381)" but the size 8381 is not accepted for nchar type (max is 8000)

Comment: It looks like some issue with rubel  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15767213/how-can-i-use-the-like-operator-to-make-this-match-in-sql-server